# Pull-back of reflexive sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a noetherian, projective scheme, $\mathcal{F}$ be a reflexive sheaf on $X$ pure of dimension $\dim(X)$ and $Y \subset X$ be a closed subscheme of $X$. Is it possible that the pull-back of $\mathcal{F}$ to $Y$ is again reflexive?

Comment: Of course it is possible. For instance, if $\mathcal{F}$ is a vector bundle (=locally free sheaf), so is its pullback (=restriction to $Y$).

Comment: @Polizzi: Are there cases when $\mathcal{F}$ is not a locally free sheaf?

Comment: Yes. A reflexive sheaf on $X$ is locally free outside a closed subset $D$ of codimension $\geq 3$. Now, for instance, take $Y$ disjoint from $D$.

Comment: @Polizzi: This is true only if $X$ is regular.

Comment: True, I'm considering the simplest case.

Comment: This sort of issue and related problems come up a lot in practice (for instance in base change).  I'll try to write down a reasonable answer giving some examples of techniques for showing this unless someone beats me to it.  In the meantime, do you have some particular sheaves in mind?  (Relative) canonical sheaves for instance?

Comment: @Schwede: I do not have a specific example in mind but it will be very helpful if you could please give some examples of techniques, you mention.

Answer (score 6):

Let $X$ be a noetherian integral scheme and $\mathscr F$ a coherent sheaf on $X$.
If $\mathscr F$ is reflexive, then $\mathscr F\big|_H$ is torsion-free for any Cartier divisor $H \subset X$, and $\mathscr F\big|_H$ is reflexive if $H$ is a general element of a basepoint-free linear system (the notion of generality here of course depends on $\mathscr F$). If $\mathscr F$ is just torsion-free, then $\mathscr F\big|_H$ is still torsion-free for $H$ general.

Some references for this are Huybrechts-Lehn, ''The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves'', Cor. 1.1.14, and Greb-Kebekus-Peternell, ''Étale fundamental groups of klt spaces'', Prop. 5.1 and 5.2.